# Last item of recycler view with multiview is messing up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a chat app, where recycler view has multiple view layouts. But the last item of each chat is not in place but when we scroll up and come back down, it comes back to its place.
Here's my adapter:

```
     @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
       viewType) {

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case TEXT_TYPE_OTHER:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);
            return new TextMessageViewHolder(view);
        case TEXT_TYPE_USER:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_single_layout_user, parent, false);
            return new TextMessageViewHolderUser(view);
        case IMAGE_TYPE_OTHER:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_image_single_layout, parent, false);
            return new ImageMessageViewHolder(view);
        case IMAGE_TYPE_USER:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_image_single_layout_user, parent, false);
            return new ImageMessageViewHolderUser(view);
        case IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_OTHER:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_image_single_layout_with_text, parent, false);
            return new ImageMessageWithTextViewHolder(view);
        case IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_USER:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_image_single_layout_with_text_user, parent, false);
            return new ImageMessageWithTextViewHolderUser(view);
    }
    return null;
}

public class TextMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView time;
    private TextView messageText;
    //private CardView cardView;
    private TextView textDate;
    private View view;

    public TextMessageViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        messageText = view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout);
        time = view.findViewById(R.id.time_text_layout);
        textDate = view.findViewById(R.id.text_chat_date);
        //cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_view);
    }
}


public class TextMessageViewHolderUser extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView timeUser;
    private TextView messageTextUser;
    private TextView textDateUser;
    //private CardView cardViewUser;
    private View view;

    public TextMessageViewHolderUser(View view) {
        super(view);
        messageTextUser = view.findViewById(R.id.message_text_layout_user);
        timeUser = view.findViewById(R.id.time_text_layout_user);
        textDateUser = view.findViewById(R.id.text_chat_date_user);
        //cardViewUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewUser);
        view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_view_user);

    }
}

public class ImageMessageWithTextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView messageImage;
    //private CardView imageMessage;
    private TextView imageText;
    private TextView imageTime;
    private TextView imageTextDate;
    private View view;

    public ImageMessageWithTextViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageText_with_text);
        imageTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text_layout_image_with_text);
        messageImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_layout_with_text);
        imageTextDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_image_chat_date);
        view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_image_view);
        //imageMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMessageWithText);
    }
}

public class ImageMessageWithTextViewHolderUser extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView messageImageUser;
    //private CardView imageMessageUser;
    private TextView imageTextUser;
    private TextView imageTimeUser;
    private TextView imageTextDateUser;
    private View view;

    public ImageMessageWithTextViewHolderUser(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageTextUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageText_with_text_user);
        imageTimeUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text_layout_image_with_text_user);
        messageImageUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_layout_with_text_user);
        imageTextDateUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_image_chat_date_user);
        view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_image_user_view);

        //imageMessageUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMessageWithTextUser);
    }
}

public class ImageMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView messageImage;
    //private CardView cardView;
    private TextView imageTime;
    private TextView imageChatDate;
    private View view;

    public ImageMessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text_layout_image);
        //cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMessage);
        messageImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_layout);
        imageChatDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_chat_date);
        view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_view);

    }
}

public class ImageMessageViewHolderUser extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView messageImageUser;
    //private CardView cardViewUser;
    private TextView imageTimeUser;
    private TextView imageChatDateUser;
    private View view;

    public ImageMessageViewHolderUser(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageTimeUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text_layout_image_user);
        //cardViewUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMessageUser);
        messageImageUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_layout_user);
        imageChatDateUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_chat_date_user);
        view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_view_user);

    }
}

        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (mMessageList.get(position).getType()){
        case 0:
            if (mMessageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(currentUserId))
                return TEXT_TYPE_USER;
            else
                return TEXT_TYPE_OTHER;
        case 1:
            if (mMessageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(currentUserId))
                return IMAGE_TYPE_USER;
            else
                return IMAGE_TYPE_OTHER;
        case 2:
            if (mMessageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(currentUserId))
                return IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_USER;
            else
                return IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_OTHER;
        default:
            return 1234567890;
    }
}


public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int listPosition) {

    final Messages object = mMessageList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    final String fromUser = object.getFrom();
    final String lastSeenTime = DateFormat.format("HH:mm", new Date(object.getTime())).toString();
    RequestBuilder<Drawable> thumbnailRequestBlogImage;
    thumbnailRequestBlogImage =glide.load(object.getThumb());

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case TEXT_TYPE_USER:
                    ((TextMessageViewHolderUser) holder).messageTextUser.setText(object.getMessage());
                    ((TextMessageViewHolderUser) holder).timeUser.setText(lastSeenTime);
                break;
            case TEXT_TYPE_OTHER:
                    ((TextMessageViewHolder) holder).messageText.setText(object.getMessage());
                    ((TextMessageViewHolder) holder).time.setText(lastSeenTime);
                break;
            case IMAGE_TYPE_USER:
                    ((ImageMessageViewHolderUser) holder).imageTimeUser.setText(lastSeenTime);
                   glide.load(object.getImage())
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().dontAnimate().dontTransform())
                            .thumbnail(thumbnailRequestBlogImage)
                            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            .into(((ImageMessageViewHolderUser) holder).messageImageUser);
                break;
            case IMAGE_TYPE_OTHER:

                    ((ImageMessageViewHolder) holder).imageTime.setText(lastSeenTime);
                    glide.load(object.getImage())
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().dontAnimate().dontTransform())
                            .thumbnail(thumbnailRequestBlogImage)
                            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            .into(((ImageMessageViewHolder) holder).messageImage);
                break;
            case IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_USER:

                    ((ImageMessageWithTextViewHolderUser) holder).imageTextUser.setText(object.getImageText());
                    ((ImageMessageWithTextViewHolderUser) holder).imageTimeUser.setText(lastSeenTime);

                    glide.load(object.getImage())
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().dontAnimate().dontTransform())
                            .thumbnail(thumbnailRequestBlogImage)
                            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            .into(((ImageMessageWithTextViewHolderUser) holder).messageImageUser);
                break;
            case IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_OTHER:

                    ((ImageMessageWithTextViewHolder) holder).imageText.setText(object.getImageText());
                    ((ImageMessageWithTextViewHolder) holder).imageTime.setText(lastSeenTime);

                    glide.load(object.getImage())
                            .apply(new RequestOptions().dontAnimate().dontTransform())
                            .thumbnail(thumbnailRequestBlogImage)
                            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            .into(((ImageMessageWithTextViewHolder) holder).messageImage);

                break;
        }
}
```

I'm using firestore to send and get messages. It's only happening with the last message.
[Here's the screenshot when I open chatActivity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwlwC.jpg)

[Here's the screenshot when I scroll up and then again down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx4ji.jpg)
I've even tried setting holder.setIsRecyclable(false) but still no success.
Here's the chatActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#cfd8dc"
tools:context=".Activities.ChatActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:id="@+id/messages_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/chat_add_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chat_message_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Message..."
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="14dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/chat_send_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the XML of your recyclerview and activity

Comment: use android studio debug tools to check what is going wrong in your onCreateViewHolder and in your onBindView holder i think at first Time your viewType is IMAGE_TYPE_OTHER but when its get recycled it changes to IMAGE_TYPE_USER and i assume its because of logical error some where in your code causing this

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not able to solve the problem. I've checked the code too, but everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was getting currentUserId in onCreateViewHolder,

```
 @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
   viewType) {

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
       ........}
```

And then using that to return itemview type in getItemView(),

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    switch (mMessageList.get(position).getType()){
    case 0:
        if (mMessageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(currentUserId))
            return TEXT_TYPE_USER;
        else
            return TEXT_TYPE_OTHER;
    case 1:
        if (mMessageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(currentUserId))
            return IMAGE_TYPE_USER;
        else
            return IMAGE_TYPE_OTHER;
    case 2:
        if (mMessageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(currentUserId))
            return IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_USER;
        else
            return IMAGE_TEXT_TYPE_OTHER;
    default:
        return 1234567890;
    }
}
```

So, I found that when inflating the last message item (which is first of my list as I'm displaying recyclerview in reverse order), my currentUserId variable was giving null, so getItemViewType returned the other layout, but after recycling currentUserId had value in it so getItemViewType returned correct layout. This was the reason why the last item was messing up at first but after recycling was shifting back to correct position.

Thanks, Amir Hossein Mirzaei.

Comment: How you solve the issue? I`m also facing the same issue from last 1 week so please help me to get rid of this problem?